# Django related_name default syntax

Tags: django, django-models

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name), related names must be unique. Again according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) the default value, (if not set explicitly by the developer) is `FOO_set`, where `FOO` is the source model name.

So if I have two foreign keys (pointing to two different models, of course), wouldn't the (default) related names be similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd like to extend the excellent answer of Willem Van Onsem. In his example the class C is related to the classes A and B. Therefore A and B have attributes `c_set`, but they are different classes. Thus the attributes `c_set`, which have the same name, exist in a different scope (namespace).

But what if the relation is of different nature. Let's take a look at different example. Imagine an application for sport teams. We have classes Person and Team. A person can play for a team or coach a team. The models would look like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    players = models.ManyToManyField('Person')
    coaches = models.ManyToManyField('Person')
```

Now this should create an attribute `team_set` to the class Person:

```
person = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
# now we want to get the teams where the person participates
person.team_set.all()
```

And there is the problem! Which relation should be used - `players` or `coaches`? Django won't allow this and ask for explicit declaration of related names.

We can fix the problem by declaring the related names, for example:

```
players = models.ManyToManyField('Person', related_name='plays_in_teams')
coaches = models.ManyToManyField('Person', related_name='trains_teams')
```

After this change we can query the teams like:

```
person.plays_in_teams.all()
person.trains_teams.all()
```

This shows the usefulness of related names. They help to create human readable queries and increase the maintainability of the code.

Comment: I'm making this the right answer, because it's more clearer and would help future visitors.  Special thanks to @Willem.

Comment: The error message shown by Django is `Reverse accessor for 'Team.players' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Team.coaches'.`

Answer (score 6):

Given you have a model `C`, with `ForeignKey`s to `A` and `B`, like:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    pass

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then there are indeed **two `c_set`s**, but these are on **different models**. So `A` objects have a `c_set`, and `B` objects have a `c_set`, but there is no confusion, since the type of object determines about which relation we are talking.

Frequently it makes sense however to specify a `related_name=...`, parameter with better nomenclature.

Comment: So when the documentation says Unique, it just means unique in that model ? What if I have 2 foreign keys pointing to the same model ?

Comment: @Jibin: yes, in case you then make migrations, it will detect this, and raise an error. But the uniqness is *per* model: you can refer to *different* models, with a different name. Furthermore in case two models have a foreign key to the *same* model, the related name should be different.